# Joint percentages in barplot ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to construct a bar plot with percentage on the y axis. I have some data in table format and want to plot it into bar plot

```
library(survival)

kidney$mortality <- ifelse(kidney$status==1, "Dead", "Alive")

table1(~ disease
       | mortality * sex, data=kidney )
```

I am trying to assess the probability of people who died in each disease category and the numbered category like this

1. For all the people in category 1 and disease other (6 total) divided by the number of dead 1s in the other disease category (6 total) with a bar at 100 percent because 6/6.

There will be a total of 8 bars in this case.

How would I work this into a solid ggplot barplot with the percent on the y axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)
library(survival)
```

### Code

```
kidney %>% 
  #Change status from 0/1 to Dead/Alive
  mutate(status = if_else(status==1, "Dead", "Alive")) %>% 
  #Count number of observations for each combination of sex, status and disease
  count(disease,status,sex) %>%
  #Grouping by next calculation by disease and sex
  group_by(disease,sex) %>% 
  mutate(
    #Total observations for each disease and sex
    N = sum(n),
    #Percentage of status by disease and sex
    p = 100*n/N
  ) %>% 
  #Filter only the dead
  filter(status == "Dead") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = disease, y = p, fill = as.factor(sex)))+
  # Adding column geometry
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())+
  # Adding text in the top of the columns
  geom_text(aes(label = round(p)),position = position_dodge(1), vjust = 2)
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Is there a way to do this where 1 and 2 are colored in the legend and instead of alive it's just the percentage dead. So only one set of other, gn, an, pkd with 2 bars each

Comment: It seems in datasets with NA's in data the code will also plot the NA's. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Yes @rj44, you can filter them, imagine you want to filter NA's from sex, would be `kidney %>% filter(!is.na(sex))`

Comment: ah sorry I meant to just edit my statement to ask if there's an option to avoid specifically using filter haha. It's easy to fix, but I'm curious why the NA's are plotted at default